How to access form submission value from field with name ending in square braces?
This is my file signup.inc.php:
    <?php

    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $username = $_GET['uid[]'];
    $pwd = $_GET['pwd'];
    $pwdRepeat = $_GET['pwdrepeat'];
    }
    else {
    header("location: ../signup.php");
    }

This is my other file,:
    <?php include 'header.php';?>

    <h2>Registrera konto!</h2>

    <div class="signup-form-form"/>
    <form style="margin: auto;" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="GET"/>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name"/>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
    <input type="text" name="uid[]" placeholder="Användarnamn"/>
    <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Lösenord"/>
    <input type="password" name="pwdrepeat" placeholder="Lösenord ... "/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit"/>Registrera konto(0())!</button>
    </form></div>

    <!--Error messages-->

    <?php include 'footer.php';?>

So, what should it say here: $username = $_GET['uid[]'];

Why is uid an array?  It doesn't makes sense considering all other fields are scalar.  $_GET['uid[]'] is not how you access it anyhow -- should be $_GET['uid'][0] ...assuming you are only submitting one.
